# How to use SELECT query in MySqlDataAdapter to grab rows from table A and grab number of rows from table B in C#? DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf, datagrid

I am using DataSet and DataTable to fill a DataGrid in WPF C#. I want to add a custom column that is not in the table and have it display the number of row WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id.
 
`SELECT tableA.id, tableA.name, (# of row from tableB WHERE tableA.id=id) FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB` 
I am not sure if it is possible to do that with one query. If not, how can I add a custoemr column to my DataGrid and display the number of rows where tableB.id = tableA.id. I am using DataSet and DataTable to Fill my DataGrid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(b.id)
FROM tableA as a
    JOIN tableB as b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.Name
ORDER BY a.id
```

To get all rows in A, with corresponding row count in from B, try something like.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, SUM(CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as rowsInB
FROM tableA as a
    LEFT JOIN tableB as b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.Name
ORDER BY a.id
```

Comment: It isn't quite working. I am returning only 1 row now and COUNT(b.id) is being returned as the sum of what would be row COUNT(b.id). I think it has something to do with ON. I will continue messing around with it.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, it was because I took out GROUP BY. I think it is working fine now, but I am trying to add ORDER BY in there somewhere, but it seems to be causing syntax error.

Comment: @kevinyu You can add `order by` at the end and it should work fine.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I just had a typo and over thought about it. Thanks a lot! I Used WHERE a.id = b.id. Is there a difference?

Comment: I also have another question, if I were to use WHERE a.id= b.id, then it will only return rows where b.id exists correct? If I used ON a.id = b.id Will it still return a row if b.id does not exists in b table? So the Count(b.id) will show as 0. That is ultimately what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, if you want to get the rows in A that are not in B you have to use an `OUTER JOIN`. For `INNER JOINs` the WHERE and the JOIN conditions are the same, but for outer joins they are not evaluated the same way.